# CiviMail Unsubscribe link goes to an empty Wordpress page

Tags: civimail, wordpress, email

How do I troubleshoot a non-working Unsubscribe link through CiviMail?

In using CiviMail to send a mass mailing, the required Unsubscribe function creates a link like this: http://get-hope-global.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mailing/unsubscribe&reset=1&jid=23&qid=42&h=68396bb3066b85d5

Following that link shows our website header and footer without any other information in between. No activity is logged on the associated record in CiviCRM.

I am using CiviCRM 4.5 on WordPress 4.2.2 to send the mailing through the transactional e-mail service Mandrill.

Comment: What are jid, qid, and h in the checksum link?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a basepage set?

Without a basepage, WordPress will use index.php and unpredictable results will occur.  Go to Administer -> System Settinngs -> CMS Database integration.  In WordPress Base Page set a page (civicrm for example), make sure that a WordPress Page (not a post) exists with the same name and slug.

Once this is set your unsubscribe url should be http://get-hope-global.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mailing/unsubscribe&reset=1&jid=23&qid=42&h=68396bb3066b85d5

Try it again and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the access controls to make sure mail user has permission to access the subscribe/unsubscribe page.  (note: I'm not sure if WordPress has this exact control)

To get to the access control go to Administer => Users and Permissions => Permissions.

Below the green box should be a link to WordPress Access Control
Look to see what your mail user has access to do.  On Drupal for unsubscribe I believe the mail user needs to ability to edit a contact and access the unsubscribe page.  Again not sure what the WP permissions are.

You might also check your apache logs or whatever webserver you are using logs.