# CiviMail Unsubscribe link goes to a generic/undefined Wordpress page

Tags: civimail, unsubscribe, opt-out

When the recipients of my mailing try to click on the "Unsubscribe" link the user is taken to a generic/undefined page that reads: "CiviCRM  Do not delete this page. Page content is generated by CiviCRM."  The user is also not marked as having opted-out of all bulk mailings.

The link generated is generated via {action.optOutUrl} which yields "http://besanthill.nfshost.com/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmailing%2Foptout&reset=1&jid=244&qid=7847&h=0db2c5d63683bd63", for example.

I've looked at the suggestions on [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2495/civimail-unsubscribe-link-goes-to-an-empty-wordpress-page) but the CMS base page and the permissions appear to be set correctly (that is, "access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages" is enabled for anonymous.)  And ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Richard

Comment: pls state the version you are on, and whether any other pages such as a payment confirmation are not working

Comment: I am running CiviCRM 5.24.5.  I have never attempted to use any other pages such as payment confirmation.

Comment: Also which version of WordPress? If it's 5.5+ then you will have to upgrade CiviCRM.

Comment: WP is 5.5.1.  Ok, I'll look into upgrading CiviCRM

Comment: I upgraded CiviCRM and the issue went away.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed. The solution was to upgrade CiviCRM to the latest version.